# Label.enabled = false Color property

Tags: vb.net, winforms

With one of my event handlers (double click cell contents in a gridview) I bring up another form that gives a summery of the contents of the row that was clicked...

When doing this, I set the original form to disabled, so that the user cannot interact with it until the summery form is closed.

Problem is that I would like to keep my labels on the original form white, but being that they are disabled as well.. they turn grey, as they are supposed to.

I have tried to set their color with the event(enabled has changed) But my half-witted solution didn't get me the results that I was looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you're actually after is a modal form. This forces the user to only interact with the new form you've opened (within your application) but they can still read what is behind. The following link is a good start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: As Makita say you possible only need change `YourForm.Show();` to `YourForm.ShowDialog();`  so the user can't change the main form until your popupform is closed.